# MySQL - Using 'WHERE Column LIKE' in the right DateTime format

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to implement a search function for my MySQL. In my application I have a page where the user sees a table from my database. He pretty much sees what you see when running `SELECT * FROM table`

My table has Integers, Strings and DateTimes. What I want is that the user can type anything in the searchbox and get a list of any row that has a substring of that text the user was searching for.

First, I am also using `CONCAT` to get one large string of every column in the table row. Here is an example:

```
SELECT Name, Fullname FROM myTable WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(Name, ' ', FullName, ' ') LIKE '%M%');
```

The problem: Lets say I want every record from 24.04. So I run the following code:

```
SELECT Name, Fullname, Date FROM myTable WHERE Date LIKE '%24.04%';
```

The problem is that the column Date isnt in the same format. Its stored as `2008-24-04 12:26:43`.

I have tried using `DATE_FORMAT`. But it does not seem to work

```
SELECT Name, Fullname, Date FROM myTable WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(Name, ' ', Fullname, ' ', DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%d.%l.%Y"), ' ') LIKE '%22.04%');
```

**Note** that the user should be able to search for anything in that table. Not only for dates. So I should still be using `LIKE '%XYZ%'`.

How do I solve this? Changing anything on the Database-Model is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `DAY` and `MONTH` functions:

```
SELECT Name, Fullname, Date FROM myTable WHERE MONTH(Date) = 4 AND DAY(Date) = 24;
```

The last SELECT could be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT Name, Fullname, Date FROM myTable WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(Name, ' ', Fullname, ' ')) LIKE '%22.04%' AND MONTH(Date) = 4 AND DAY(Date) = 22;
```

But I don't see why you would check names against a date

**EDIT**

In your question you said you tried to format the date. In the format string there was an error. You used `DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%d.%l.%Y")` which would convert to "day.hour.year". This should give the right result: `DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%d.%m.%Y")`

Comment: Like you can see in my first example, I should be able to not only search for Dates, but also for Text. So basically, Even if I search for '4.0' I am getting the record with 24.04 as a result. 'LIKE' should still be used

Comment: I don't really understand. You originally said `The problem is that the column Date isnt in the same format. Its stored as 2008-12-02 12:26:43` and that you tried it with dateformat. This should solve the problem

Comment: How do you determine which column is used in the where clause?

Comment: Every column I use in my `SELECT` will also be used in my `WHERE` clause

Comment: I think you should explain your problem in more detail (in the original question)